# How to handle object property if object type is literal and key type is string?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
type objType = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

const f = (key: string, obj: objType) => {
    if (key in obj) {
        return obj[key];        
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But this code [raises a error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKwCrmgXigbwFBT1AQwC4oBGAGl3zhICZsBfbbAYxgDsBnYKAMygwAKANYQQJbgCcAluwDm5WIhLxkqAJQCAfFip5p-EWKiylCTTnxWokiMACuk9mYDaokAF0A3Nfx6oDFAQADac0Ja+NnaOzuz2wcFe-kwMQA). My question is, how to handle this properly? I know I could use switch/case, but I don't like it because objType can have dozens of properties. I also don't want to use type assertion for key because it's *actually* just a string. What I want is to tell Typescript: "Hey, sometimes this is one of objType's keys, and when it is, everything is fine so let me reference objType[key]. But when it isn't, everything is fine either because I don't care about objType[key] and return some other value instead". It seems to be pretty simple logic to me, but somehow it appears there's no way to explain it to Typescript.

So, what am I missing? How should I handle this in the most readable, elegant way? I know I can make it work using type assertion or ts-ignore, but it seems to be such a common use case I can't believe there is no proper way to do this.

Comment: instead of `key: string`, use `key: keyof typeof obj`

Comment: I'm afraid it wouldn't work because key *isn't* keyof typeof obj. I mean, I could use type assertion to cast key to keyof typeof obj, but that would defeat purpose of typing.

Comment: `type objType = { [key: string]: number }` ?

Comment: but then my function won't have proper signature